# How i can delete elements from object in recursive $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, i have this data object:

```
var data = {
    'some': [
        {'id': 10, 'info': [{'next': 11}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 11, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 12, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 20}, {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 13, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 14, 'info': [{'next': 12}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 15, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 16, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 14}]}, 
        {'id': 17, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 13}, {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 18, 'info': [{'next': 15}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 11}]}, 
        {'id': 20, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}
    ]
};
```

I want delete all elements with `id` where contains in `next`, for example, from data object above, i want get something like this

```
    var data = {
        'some': [
            {'id': 10, 'info': [{'next': 11}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
            {'id': 16, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 14}]}, 
            {'id': 17, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 13}, {'next':  0}]}, 
            {'id': 18, 'info': [{'next': 15}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
            {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
            {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 11}]}, 
        ]
    };
```

I write this script, but it return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, why?

var cleanData = function (d

```
ata) {
    $.each(data['some'], function (_is, some) {
        $.each(some['info'], function (_in, next) {
            if (next['next']) 
                $.each(data['some'], function (_is2, some2) {
                    if (some2['id'] == next['next']) 
                        data['some'].remove(_is2);
                });
        });
    });

    return data;
};
```

[My example on JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7hgxpd6L/)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand which elements should be removed. What does "contains in `next`" mean?

Comment: @FelixKling it means, that if `next != 0`, i need remove from `some` line with `[some][i][id] == next`.

Comment: So you want to keep the elements in the `some` array that have at least one object in their `info` array with a non-zero `next` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this in two steps: First find all the IDs that are contained in any `next` object. Then filter the array and remove the rows with that IDs.

Example:

```
// Build ids table
var idsToRemove = data.some.reduce(function(ids, row) {
  return row.info.reduce(function(ids, obj) {
    return ids[obj.next] = true, ids;
  }, ids);
}, {});

// Filter out rows with those IDs
data.some = data.some.filter(function(row) {
  return !idsToRemove[row.id];
});

console.log(data);
```

```js
var data = {
    'some': [
        {'id': 10, 'info': [{'next': 11}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 11, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 12, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 20}, {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 13, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 14, 'info': [{'next': 12}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 15, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 16, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 14}]}, 
        {'id': 17, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 13}, {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 18, 'info': [{'next': 15}, {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}, 
        {'id': 19, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next': 11}]}, 
        {'id': 20, 'info': [{'next': 0},  {'next': 0}, {'next': 0},  {'next':  0}]}
    ]
};

// Build ids table
var ids = data.some.reduce(function(ids, row) {
  return row.info.reduce(function(ids, obj) {
    return ids[obj.next] = true, ids;
  }, ids);
}, {});

// Filter out rows with those IDs
data.some = data.some.filter(function(row) {
  return !ids[row.id];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I think renaming your `ids` to `idsToRemove` would make your example slightly easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: [See Andrew's answer on this page.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450281/152648) It's a much cleaner and safer solution.**

In short, you can't. You'll have to use a regular `for` loop with an index, instead, so that you can keep up with the new length of your array.

```
$.each(data['some'], function (_is, some) {
    $.each(some['info'], function (_in, next) {
        if (next['next']) 
            for(var i=0, len=data['some'].length; i < len; i++) {
                var some2 = data['some'][i];
                if (some2['id'] == next['next']) {
                    data['some'].remove(_is2);
                    // Decrement i since the next item will now be in the place of the one you removed.
                    i--;
                    // Decrement len since your array now holds one less item.
                    len--;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.filter is great for a problem like this. This code should produce what you're looking for:

```
data.some = data.some.filter(function(item) {
    return item.info.filter(function(i) {
        return i.next > 0;
    }).length > 0;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what the OP wants: http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx0uga/. It removes and leaves the wrong rows.

Comment: @FelixKling Why was the row with id 12 removed in the OP's example?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Because the row with id 14 contains `{next: 12}`. It's not described very well, but his comments clarifies it a bit *"it means, that if `next != 0`, i need remove from `some` line with `[some][i][id] == next`"* (at least that's my interpretation :-/ )

Comment: Ahh, I see it now, it looks like Grinn misunderstood the question in the same way I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for while length is greater than zero and delete in index one from array

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because not every object in the array has a property with a key of 'id'

I'm not exactly clear on what is supposed to be removed, but if it's everything that's first key is 'next, change this:

```
if (some2['id'] == next['next'])
```

to this:

```
if (some2[0] == 'next')
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hgxpd6L/1/)

HTH,

-Ted